# RSpec HtmlMatchers have_tag: can we use regular expression to match HTML attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec3

Trying to spec for a part of value of the the `src` attribute in an `img` tag rendered by one of my views, I was hoping to use the following syntax:

```
is_expected.to have_tag 'img', with: {src: /thumb_product\.png/}
```

It does not work, which is weird because the expression seems to be correctly interpreted by nokogiri (see the `(?-mix:...)` criteria)

```
expected following:
<div class='active uploaded_image'>
<img alt="Thumb product" src="/uploads/tmp/1404970363-22080-9933/thumb_product.png" />
</div>

to have at least 1 element matching "img[src='(?-mix:thumb_product\.png)']", found 0.
```

So I wonder if I forgot something, or if it's simply not possible. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually, to test that `src` string ends with the expected name of the file:

```
is_expected.to have_tag 'img[src$="thumb_product.png"]'
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking into matching tags' text with a regular expression:

According to `RSpecHtmlMatchers#have_tag`'s documentation (https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-html-matchers/RSpecHtmlMatchers:have_tag), you can pass a regular expression to the `have_tag` method.

Example:

```rb
is_expected.to have_tag 'img', /^something(.*)in\-the\-text/
```

And, even though it's not explicit in the documentation, you can also match attributes of tags with regular expressions, for example:

```rb
is_expected.to have_tag 'img', :with => {:class => /some\-class\-(one|two)$/}
```

Not sure why it didn't work for the original poster with the `src` attribute. It does work for the `class` attribute at least.